# How to compute the sparseness of files with holes?

Tags: macos, file, hfs

I have in a folder several files which are unfinished torrent files. On a HFS filesystem the `du` command returns the size of the file as if it has not hole in it.

How do you compute the ratio between the empty blocks and the block with actual data in them ? So far I'm doing this by dividing the size of a fast gzip compressed version of the file by the apparent size.

I'm not writing an application. I'm trying to find which files created by transmission (a bittorent client) are not complete.

Comment: Depending on the file system to track the holes for you seems like poor application design, since the blocks of your data transfer may not precisely match the way the file system organizes the pages of the file. Your torrent application should keep track of the blocks it has received in a separate file.

Comment: I'm not writing an application. I'm trying to find which files created by transmission (a bittorent client) are not complete.

Comment: Since this is not a programming-related question, it does not belong here but on [Superuser](http://superuser.com/). A moderator will probably migrate it.

Answer (score 2):

`ls -ksl filename` will display the actual allocated on-disk space in the first column, in *kilobytes* (not bytes). A sparse file will have allocated space less than the actual size of the file, *but* having a greater-or-equal allocated size does *not* guarantee that the file has been fully downloaded, just that each block of the file has had something written to. To verify if the file has been fully downloaded, you should validate the checksum from the `.torrent` file, which some command-line torrent clients can do for you (e.g. `ctorrent -c`, available from Homebrew or MacPorts).

Comment: In the case of files created by Tranmission, the -s flag does not help. The files always looks like all their blocks are allocated. However I don't know if it's because of HFS or tranmission.

Comment: It is not because of HFS, as I have tested my answer with actual sparse files on an HFS partition. Apparently your files are not sparse at all.

Comment: +1 for the hash, that is reliable way to do this.